# Best way to import modules with 'dynamic' and no SSR plus OnsenUI

Tags: next.js, onsen-ui

people.

https://nextjs.org/docs#dynamic-import

It's nice and easy. But: what's the best way to import more than 1 module from the same library?
Specifically, I would like to work with Onsen UI (to build a PWA) with Next.js. Onsen just render with 'window' object, that doesn't exists on server-side. So, I'm thinking to import dynamically these components and render on client-side.

I have to import several modules from 'react-onsenui', like Page, Button, etc, etc.

```
const Page = dynamic(
    () => import('react-onsenui').then(
        mod => mod.Page
    ),
    {
        ssr: false,
    }
);
```

I have the Page module available on this way. But I would like to import all I need one time. Is it possible?